# Is it possible to get 3rd party API using client-side script only

Tags: javascript, api, client-side-scripting

Let say I have access to check shipping cost by using 3rd party API with API-KEY

Is it possible to get/request the data using client-side script only (like javascript or mustache or else)?

Here is the [documentation](https://rajaongkir.com/dokumentasi/starter) from the provider

Comment: If you have an api key then this is possible. The only problem is sharing your api key with client so anyone can take it. The solution for this is to say third party service your host, so only calls from your host and your key will processed.

Comment: do you mean I should use host for server-side script? if it yes then it will leads me the another problem, :) I only using static web app in localhost since the purpose is only for learn and practice

Comment: If it is only for learning and you will not expose this to the public - forget what I said before and use it from localhost with your key. But, still, care not to expose key to the source control or public access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with AJAX.

If you had to send a GET to `https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province` , the AJAX request will look as follows:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "https://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province",
         type: "GET",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('key', 'API Key');},
         success: function() { //do something here post the GET }
      });
```

UPDATE:

You will need to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for `$.ajax`. You can do that by including the jQuery library in your project. In your `<head>`, add the following:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This should enable you to use AJAX for sending asynchronous network requests.

I have written one request where I send a GET to the https://swapi.co/api/people/1/ and display the name in div

https://jsfiddle.net/raj7desai/mtdnzoh0/

Comment: It will be nice to mention fetch method as far as jQuery not required

Comment: @raj7desai would you mind to explain me how should I integrate the AJAX with HTML form input, or maybe axample from your code above

Comment: It seems you get CORS errors. Same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637361/raja-ongkir-api-get-with-ajax-jquery#